# Appending user input and strings with Assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am writing my first program in assembly and what the program is supposed to do is take two input. The first input is the user's name, the second input is a class. The final output will be user name loves this class. So I need a way to append user name loves and class together and print it in one line.

This is the output I get:

```
Please enter your name
test 
You entered: 
test 
Please enter your
favorite class test 
You entered:
```

I figured I just use mov to place the strings in different segments of the table and then I could print out the whole table. Why doesn't this work?

This is my assembly code

```
  %include "io.mac"
.STACK 100H 
.DATA
   msg1  db "Please enter your name",0
   msg2  db "You entered: ",0
   msg3  db "Please enter your favorite class",0
   msg4  db "loves",0
   table1 TIMES 20 DW 0
   .CODE
        .STARTUP

    PutStr msg1  ; print msg1 on the output
    nwln
    GetStr  [table1]    ; input string into first space in table
    nwln
    PutStr msg2
    PutStr [table1] ; output string in register table
    nwln

    mov WORD [table1+2], msg4 ;append msg 4 to table

    PutStr msg3  ; print msg3 on the output
    nwln
    GetStr [table1+4]   ; input string into next space in table
    nwln
    PutStr msg2 ; print msg2 on the output
    PutStr table1   ; output the entire string of table1

    nwln



    done:                        
        .EXIT
```

Comment: `PutStr table1   ; output the entire string of table1` <-- Are you absolutely certain that `PutStr`actually supports a string table as an argument? What does the documentation for this macro say?

Comment: Looks like you stepped on `msg1` somehow; your sample output shows the 2nd prompt is only `Please enter your`.  Single-step with a debugger to see what happened.  Also use the debugger to see if `PutStr [table1]` is any different from `PutStr table1` (it probably isn't.)

Comment: "I just use mov to place the strings" Yeah, that's not going to work. Asm doesn't really grok strings. `table1` is actually going to be a number, reflecting the address in memory where the data lives. So if (for instance) table1 was 100, then `table1+2` would be 104 (since table1 is dw). Likewise `msg4` is a number. Put together, `mov WORD [table1+2], msg4` would mean "move the number for `msg4` into the space 4 bytes into table1." If table1 contains "test", then the 4th byte (since the first byte is 0) would be the null terminator at the end of the string in table1. SO not what you intended.

Comment: Any suggestion as to how this should be accomplished?

Comment: Copying bytes from one place to another isn't that complex, just (a bit) tedious.  Read a byte from the first string and write it to the second.  Then increment both the source and dest pointers and repeat until you find the null terminator at the end of msg4.  Since you already have a library of functions (PutStr, GetStr, etc), I'd look to see if there was any existing copy routine I could use.  Failing that, I'd write one and `call` it.